# How to simultaneously send and get data in React using axios?

Tags: javascript, php, reactjs, axios

So I have this onClick function in React where contents from one div will be changed depending on the selected item in another div. The function looks like this which will make one post request to send which data to receive and one get request to get the actual data.

```
handleClick(event) {
this.setState({
  selected: event.target.innerText
});

axios.post("/e-commerce_with_purephp/acom_cms_admin/database/serveData.php", {category: this.state.selected})
.then(res => console.log("Response: " + res.parse))
.catch(error => console.log("Error: " + error))

axios
.get("/e-commerce_with_purephp/acom_cms_admin/database/serveData.php")
.then(response => response.data)
.then(data => {
  this.setState({
    ItemData: data
  })
})
}
```

And my serveData.php looks like this

```
<?php
include("connection.php");

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST") {
$category = $_POST['category'];
}

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "GET") {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `$category`";
    $result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql);
    echo "[";
for ($i = 0; $i < mysqli_num_rows($result); $i++) {
    echo ($i > 0 ? ',' : '') . json_encode(mysqli_fetch_object($result));
}
echo "]";
  } 

?>
```

This does not work fine unless I defined the category. But in that case, it will only work with one data and it's hard coded. I don't want to pull all the data from the database in one click as it will take a longer time in real world to get all the data. I am new to Axios and I referenced certain article from web.

Answer (score 1):

1. [client JS] you want to do it all in one get call
2. [backend PHP] don't split those two actions in PHP. Don't set category in POST and then try to use it in GET call. Those are two different calls and PHP won't persist `$category` variable between the calls

```
axios.post("/e-commerce_with_purephp/acom_cms_admin/database/serveData.php", {category: this.state.selected})
.then(response => response.data)
.then(data => {
  this.setState({
    ItemData: data
  })
});
})
.catch(error => console.log("Error: " + error))
```

Comment: I'm also thinking yours should work. But I think "serveData.php" doesn't properly receive {category} because my console keeps saying me the $category from php is undefined

Answer (score 0):

I think it has to do with data types. I have declared it as a FormData and added a header as a configuration and everything works fine now

```
let cat = new FormData()
cat.append('category', event.target.innerText)

axios({
  method: 'post',
  url: '/e-commerce_with_purephp/acom_cms_admin/database/serveData.php',
  data: cat,
  config: { headers: {'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' }}})
  .then(response => response.data)
  .then(data => {
    this.setState({
      ItemData: data
    })
  })
```